# the fragment can have presenter in MVP?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, presenter

I am starting the studying about MVP in one project android and I found one question  interesting,  the fragment can have one own presenter?

Comment: It can either have a presenter shared with the Activity, or its own presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. MVP architecture provides a presenter for every `Activity` and `Fragment` in the project.